# List all routes in Zend Framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

As most topics about getting a full list in ZF are about ZF2 I'm not able to generate a full list in ZF of all routes that my app has in it's config files.

Do I need zftool for this or can I also parse them as an array in my app somewhere ?

Comment: Are you asking how to get all of the routes in ZF 1 or ZF 3? Your question title and question content do not match...

Comment: Indeed, in ZF3.

Comment: In any Factory you could use Mehmet's answer to pass what you need to whatever class then ;) Mind, his answer does not include that you might need to get the ServiceLocator/ServiceManager from the container first when your Factory didn't get passed the ServiceLocator/ServiceManager but a specific manager (e.g. ControllerManager). In this case you'll have to do `$container->getServiceLocator()->get('config')` (or `->get('Router')`)

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch `routes` from config via service manager;

```
/** @var \Interop\Container\ContainerInterface $container */
$container->get('config')['router']['routes'] // its array ofcourse
```

gives your routes config. Also you can use `Router` too;

```
/** @var \Zend\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack|\Zend\Router\SimpleRouteStack $router */
$router = $container->get('Router');

/** @var \Zend\Router\PriorityList $routes */
$routes = $router->getRoutes();
```

Each element of `$routes` stack is depends on your config.

Comment: This is for ZF1 and ZF2 if you ask me, ServiceManager is not in ZF3 anymore ?

Comment: Service manager is still there but this's for factory. If you are trying to get routes in action, no you can't. You have to fetch them in factory and inject to controller.